# Angular 2+ retain form array values when adding new form input field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-form)

When I try to add new form input in form array, the whole form gets cleared and adds a new input field.

***HTML***

```
<form [formGroup]="arrayForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitArrayForm()">
<div formArrayName="dataInForm">
 <div *ngFor="let item of arrayForm.get('dataInForm')['controls']; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
   <input type="text" formControlName="randomNameFCN" name="someName">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
 <button type="button" (click)="addArrayFormField1()">Add Form Field Type 1</button>
 <button type="button" (click)="addArrayFormField2()">Add Form Field Type 2</button>
</form>
{{arrayForm.value | json}}
```

***.TS***

```
export class ArrayFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }
  randomData: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Sharpe', value: 37, },
    { id: 2, name: 'And', value: 45, },
    { id: 3, name: 'The', value: -12, }
  ];
  arrayForm: FormGroup;
  dataInFormElement: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.arrayForm = this.fb.group({
      dataInForm: this.fb.array([])
    })
    this.setValues(this.randomData);
  }

  setValues(data){
    const dataInFormControl = <FormArray>this.arrayForm.get('dataInForm')['controls'];
    data.forEach(element => {
      this.dataInFormElement = this.fb.group({
        randomNameFCN: [{value: element.name, disabled: true}]
      })
      dataInFormControl.push(this.dataInFormElement);
    }) 
  }
  addArrayFormField1(){
    const dataInFormControl = <FormArray>this.arrayForm.controls['dataInForm'];
    dataInFormControl.push(this.fb.group({
      randomNameFCN: [{ value: '', disabled: false }]
    }))
  }
  addArrayFormField2(){
    const dataInFormControl = <FormArray>this.arrayForm.get('dataInForm')['controls'];
    dataInFormControl.push(this.fb.group({
      randomNameFCN: [{ value: '', disabled: false }]
    }))
  }
  onSubmitArrayForm(){
    console.log(this.arrayForm);
  }
}
```

On initial load the json output `{{arrayForm.value | json}}` shows

```
{ "dataInForm": [ 
 { "randomNameFCN": "Sharpe" }, 
 { "randomNameFCN": "And" }, 
 { "randomNameFCN": "The" } ] }
```

which is okay. That's how I want it to be
But when I click `addArrayFormField1()` button, `arrayForm` gets cleared and json output shows
`{ "dataInForm": [ { "randomNameFCN": "" } ] }`
And on clicking `addArrayFormField2()` button, `arrayForm` doesn't add any values and json output shows old values only.

What I want is when I submit the form it should add it to current `dataForm` and should show

```
{ "dataInForm": [ 
 { "randomNameFCN": "Sharpe" }, 
 { "randomNameFCN": "And" }, 
 { "randomNameFCN": "The" },
 { "randomNameFCN": "NewName1" },
 { "randomNameFCN": "NewName2" },
 ] }
```

How do I achieve this?
And what is the difference between `addArrayFormField1()` and `addArrayFormField2()`?

Please refer the [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-form) to see it visually.

Answer (score 0):

declare dataInFormControl as global

```
dataInFormControl : FormArray
```

everytime you do this

```
dataInFormControl  = <FormArray>this.arrayForm.get('dataInForm')
```

you create a new FormArray

```
  setValues(data){
    this.dataInFormControl  = <FormArray>this.arrayForm.get('dataInForm')['controls'];
    data.forEach(element => {
      this.dataInFormElement = this.fb.group({
        randomNameFCN: [{value: element.name, disabled: true}]
      })
      this.dataInFormControl.push(this.dataInFormElement);
    }) 
  }
  addArrayFormField1(){

   this.dataInFormControl.push(this.fb.group({
      randomNameFCN: [{ value: '', disabled: false }]
    }))

  }
  addArrayFormField2(){
    this.dataInFormControl.push(this.fb.group({
      randomNameFCN: [{ value: '', disabled: false }]
    }))
  }
```

Comment: check with this https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-form-8rqaej